# Sqlit3 not accepting blank spaces in input

Tags: sqlite

I have a table trails in sqlite3 database (that is dealing with bike trails whose schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE trails (ID integer primary key, name text, city text, state char(2), length integer, ascent integer, difficulty char(2), description text);
```

And then I try and insert a value into it:

```
INSERT INTO trails (name, city, state, length, ascent, difficulty, description) VALUES (‘Blue'Sky’,‘Fort Collins’,‘CO’, 6, 300, ‘bg’, ‘cool trail’);
```

I thought that the data type text would take any kind of string given (even those with strings, such as a paragraph). What is going wrong?

Comment: You're using non-ASCII quote characters (`‘’`), which SQLite likely doesn't parse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character for string can be single quote `'` or double quote `"`.  Use double quote when string contains a single quote.

```
CREATE TABLE trails (ID integer primary key, name text, city text, state char(2), length integer, ascent integer, difficulty char(2), description text);

INSERT INTO trails (name, city, state, length, ascent, difficulty, description) VALUES ("Blue'Sky","Fort Collins","CO", 6, 300, "bg", "cool trail");
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. Also, I was writing queries in Google Docs, and copying and pasting into the terminal. A word of caution to anybody who comes across this: write your queries in a text editor!